# Ftp proxy using nginx

Tags: proxy, ftp, nginx

I'm trying to set-up a simple ftp proxy using Nginx. Right now my configuration is like this:

```
server {
    listen 21;
    server_name 52.49.13.91;
    location / {
        proxy_pass ftp://my.ftpsite.com/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 20;
    server_name 52.49.13.91;
    location / {
        proxy_pass ftp://my.ftpsite.com/;
    }
}
```

But i got the following error from nginx: `invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ftp-proxy:5`

Is nginx even capable to do this? How can I achieve this?

Comment: First of all, read up on FTP passive mode. Next, because a “native” FTP proxy needs access to the command stream, it does not support encryption. The question is: What are you actually trying to achieve? Making some FTP host appear as if it were hosted on your domain?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to connect from my computer to a FTP host that only accepts connections from a specific ip address that I can control.

Comment: I see. In that case, I recommend using a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: You might look into using the [`mod_proxy`](https://github.com/Castaglia/proftpd-mod_proxy) module for ProFTPD, which creates an FTP proxy.  (Note that I'm the author.)

Answer (score 3):

nginx can do SMTP/POP3/IMAP:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/mail-proxy/

aswell as HTTP:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

and the PROXY protocol:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/proxy-protocol/
http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt

Maybe you can use a custom module to support ftp:
https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module

But by default nginx doesn't support FTP as proxy protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Use upstream nginx module. It can upstream tcp streams. But you will need describe all ports in config - command and data.

Comment: Can you go into some more detail on how you think this will work? Please take our [tour] and see [answer].

Comment: `But you will need describe all ports in config` even a basic knowledge of the FTP protocol would tell you this is a non-starter.  FTP passive mode (most common) dynamically opens new ports.  You can't define a port map up front.